# Only get to retrieve last datasets in firebase through recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I wish to retrieve all the data but not only the last 2 sets.

Is there any solutions to retrieve every data from firebase?

Is is because the for loop or array list is having problem?

[image]

=================================================

**Updated Photo**

I'm trying to retrieve the data [matricno,password and temp]

But the output is only the two sets data inside key [Mdl3FODHWV6zv9d2rNr]

[image]

When i try to click on each CardView, the data output is the only the third output photo for three of these CardView.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

=================================================

**Userlist1.java**

```
public class userlist1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database,ab;
    MyAdapter1 myAdapter1;
    ArrayList<Report1> list;
    String uid;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist1);

        user = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userlist1);


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class Information");
        ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child(key).child("Attendance");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter1 = new MyAdapter1(this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter1);


        ab.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Report1 report1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report1.class);
                    list.add(report1);


                }

                myAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyAdapter1.java:

```
public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Report1> list;

    public MyAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Report1> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item1,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Report1 report1 = list.get(position);
        holder.matricno.setText(report1.getMatricno());
        holder.password.setText(report1.getPassword());
        holder.temp.setText(report1.getTemp());
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView matricno, password, temp;
        public View view;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            matricno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmno);
            password = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvpassword);
            temp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtemperature);




            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View itemView) {

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Data added into database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Report1.java:

```
public class Report1 {
    public String matricno;
    public String password;
    public String temp;

    public Report1(){
    }

    public String getMatricno() {
        return matricno;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }
}
```

================================================================

**Updated New Code**

**Userlist.java**

```
public class userlist extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database, ab;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Report> list;
    String uid;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    Menu menu;
    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);

        user = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userlist);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.action_search);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class Information");
        ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        ab.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Report report = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report.class);
                    list.add(report);

                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_dateascending:
                Collections.sort(list, Report.ReportDateOldestComparator);
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "Sort by Date [Oldest - Latest]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_descending:
                Collections.sort(list, Report.ReportDateLatestComparator);
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "Sort by Date [Latest - Oldest]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                // Not implemented here
                return false;
            default:
                break;
        }
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>implements Filterable {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<Report> list;
    ArrayList<Report> listfilter;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Report> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listfilter = list;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Report report = list.get(position);
        holder.time.setText(report.getTime());
        holder.duration.setText(report.getDuration());
        holder.info.setText(report.getInfo());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    list = listfilter;
                } else {
                    List<Report> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Report row : listfilter) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getInfo().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getTime().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }
                    list = (ArrayList<Report>) filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = list;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                list = (ArrayList<Report>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView duration, time, info;
        public View view;
       

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtemp);
            duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstName);
            info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmatno);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
            String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View itemView) {

                    sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("key", key);
                    editor.putString("temp", temp);
                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), userlist1.class);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);// pass key to next activity;

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Data retrieved from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Report.java**

```
public class Report {

    public String duration;
    public String time;
    public String info;

    public Report(){

    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }


    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public static Comparator<Report> ReportDateOldestComparator = new Comparator<Report>() {
        @Override

        public int compare(Report o1, Report o2) {
            return o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime());

        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Report> ReportDateLatestComparator = new Comparator<Report>() {
        @Override

        public int compare(Report o1, Report o2) {
            return o2.getTime().compareTo(o1.getTime());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see the listener you attach to `ab` already reads and processes all `Attendance` records. But since there are only two child nodes in the database, it will of course only show those two nodes in the app. Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, so can you edit your question to clarify: when you step through your code line by line in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just update the images and questions above. Do you mind to lend me a hand?

Comment: The UI is only showing the attendance nodes of the first child node, because that's what you tell it to load from the database here: `ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child(key).child("Attendance")`. Are you instead looking for it to load all attendance nodes under any `Student Attend`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely true Frank!

Comment: cardView [a] = [MdkeONsLFaBKDgyKMU]                                  
cardView [b] = [Mdkf_TBTWI4D6yRyGLa] & [MdkfYdaClyJXCIT2XEN]                    cardView [c] = [Mdl3FODHWV6zv9d2rNr]] & more

Comment: @AlexMamo do you mind to help me in this question?

Comment: The "uid" is the ID of the student, right? And as also Frank van Puffelen asked, you want to load all attendance nodes under any UID. Is this correct? Please respond with @.

Comment: The "uid" is [Xq2L8Ov4pfPoEBhV16Hr5Wvbjmy2] while the student id is the key below attendance example [MdkeONsLFaBK9DgyKMu], [-Mdkf_TBTWI4D6yRyGLa] and more. Yeap, i would like to load all attendance nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the `Attendance` from all child nodes under `Student Attend`, you first need to load the data from all those nodes:

```
ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend");
...
ab.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

Since we'll load data from a higher level in the database, we'll need to navigate across the `key` and `"Attendance"` in your `onDataChange` method now:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                //  loop over `key` level children
  for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) { 
                                                //  loop over Attendance children
    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : childSnapshot.child("Attendance").getChildren()){
      Report1 report1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report1.class);
      list.add(report1);
    }
  }

  myAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
  throw databaseError.toException(); //  never ignore errors
}
```

Comment: thanks for you code, I finally get to retrieve every attendance. Now, i have a new issue. I'm trying to implements a OnClickListener on the userlist.java in order to get the specific data in userlist1.java. May I know how to fix my code?

Comment: Hoping results is in [updated image 3] : Onclick[info:test3] ->  display 1 attendance //Onclick[info:rea] ->display 2 attendance